# Html/JavaScript event when element is dragged onto another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I have an HTML grid, I want to rearrange the elements A and B inside a grid when element A is dragged onto another element B. This should happen before dropping the element.

Is it possible to capture the event on element B when element A is dragged on it?
I don't want to wait until the user drops the element, I need to rearrange when an element is dragged on it.

Comment: ondragenter....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [dragenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragenter) event.

```js
ondragstart = e => e.dataTransfer.setData('text', '');
// set the class when entering over #target
target.ondragenter = e => target.classList.add('draghover');
// remove when leaving
target.ondragleave = e => target.classList.remove('draghover');
```

```css
#target {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#target.draghover {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true">drag me over the target</div>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's the **[`ondrag()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ondrag)** event handler which is triggered while an element is being dragged. If you want to trigger a function at the very start of the drag action, there's also the **[`ondragstart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ondragstart)** event handler.

If you want to capture when the element is dragged *over* the element (but not dropped), there's **[`ondragenter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ondragenter)** which triggers once, as the elemement is dragged *into* the element, and also **[`ondragover()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ondragover)**, which triggers repeatedly as an element is dragged *over* the element.